# MySQL Table indexation

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have table with 11 fields.
I am making SELECT query to get data for specific reason.

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `A` WHERE b IS NOT NULL, c IS NOT NULL, d IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY e DESC
```

I have made index on `(b,c,d)` AND `(e)`

MySQL `EXPLAIN` shows possible_keys that group index, but key NULL, and in extra section there is - `Using where; Using filesort`

Full Explain:

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
1|SIMPLE|m|ALL|get_movies|NULL|NULL|NULL|6694|Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Please post the *complete* `EXPLAIN` result.

Comment: try add `UNIQE` key for (ID,b,c,d)